# Getting values from array in Cosmos Db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My document that I save in Cosmos DB looks like this:

```
{
   "id": "abc123",
   "myProperty": [
      "1905844b-6ca9-4967-ba40-a736b685ca62",
      "b03cc85c-ef0b-4f48-9c31-800de089190a"
   ]
}
```

As you can see, in the `myProperty` property, I have an array of GUID values and I want to read them as an array/list of GUID values but I'm having trouble formulating the correct `SELECT` statement.

The output I'm looking for is:

```
[
   "1905844b-6ca9-4967-ba40-a736b685ca62",
   "b03cc85c-ef0b-4f48-9c31-800de089190a"
]
```

The closest I could get is this `SELECT statement:

```
SELECT VALUE c.myProperty FROM c WHERE c.id = "abc123"
```

But this doesn't give me exactly what I want either. This gives me an array within an array i.e.

```
[
   [
      "1905844b-6ca9-4967-ba40-a736b685ca62",
      "b03cc85c-ef0b-4f48-9c31-800de089190a"
   ]
]
```

What should my `SELECT` statement look like to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can ever get anything else, because cosmos db will always return an array in response to a query because potentially there can be 0-infinity results. so you will always get a top level array that will wrap all your results (even if you have only one)

Comment: I think you're right. In my code, I was able to get the results I was looking for by expecting a `List<Guid>`. Thanks!

Comment: Just did. Thanks!

Comment: This is correct, if you look at the client library it will give you back a List/array of a type, meaning it's set up to expect more than one. If you want to abstract this you can write some helper code to essentially make a SingleOrDefault method on the iterator.